# How to use cookies in Twig?

Tags: 8, theming, cookies

I'm trying to create a conditional twig function in a template I created for my website's home page (page--front.html.twig). Twig can supposedly do this out of the box, but I can't get this approach to work. The h1 is not being rendered, and no errors are being thrown. Here's the resource I used: http://enarion.net/news/2012/access-cookies-in-a-twig-template-using-symfony2/

In my template, I've added the following code:

```
{% if app.request.cookies.has('loader-activated') %}
    <h1>You have chosen your cookie brand!</h1>
{% endif %}
```

I'm using Cookie.js to declare my cookies. I've confirmed that it is working using a Chrome extension:
[image]

Am I doing something wrong? I'm not strictly a developer, and have very limited abilities with Drupal 8 templating, so I'm sure it's something pretty obvious. If app.request.cookies isn't the best approach, what else should I use? I'd prefer that it is something simple, if possible!

Comment: Is `{{ dump(app.request.cookies) }}` or `{{ app.request.cookies.get('loader-activated') }}` returning anything?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to correctly use cookies? (Twig and cache context)](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/269067/how-to-correctly-use-cookies-twig-and-cache-context)

Comment: @leymannx Neither return anything. I've looked at that post, but it's not very straight forward for me.

Comment: Thats because that is a symfony application construct, they will be empty because Drupal does not have those.

Comment: That means the other answer may be the way to go. Read cookies with PHP in a preprocess function and pass the value to Twig. But then you still need to find a way to bust the cache somehow.